# Including section in table of contents without its page number

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

How do I include something from an unnumbered page in table of contents?

Also: How can I add something with a page number to the table of contents without the page number being displayed?

Comment: Your question isn't really so clear on the layout you want. Normally omitting the number in (say) a chapter title page is just considered a feature of the design: the page still has a number, it is just not shown on the page, and tables of contents can (and do) use that number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two commands to explicitly insert material in the table of contents:

```
\addtocontents{ext}{text}
```

and

```
\addcontentsline{ext}{type}{text}
```

where `ext` is the table of contents type (e.g., `toc`, `lof`) and type indicates how the `text` is going to be formatted (you can create new types by defining new `\l@type` commands).

`\addcontentsline` adds the page number, while `\addtocontents` adds `text` to `ext`.